# Ctrl + arrow keys for tmux not working in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, putty, tmux

I'm using PuTTY to ssh into a Debian machine. When I try to use Ctrl + [arrow key] to resize panes in tmux, the active pane just switches as if I was not holding Ctrl. Other Ctrl key shortcuts work fine. When I try the same thing using a different terminal, the shortcut works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the following line to `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"
```

Source: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/bsd/src/tmux-1.3/FAQ

> **Ctrl and arrow keys doesn't work in putty! What do I do?**
>
> putty inverts the sense of the cursor key mode on ctrl, which is a bit hard for tmux to detect properly. To get ctrl keys right, change the terminfo settings so kUP5 (Ctrl-Up etc) are the adjusted versions, and disable smkx/rmkx so tmux doesn't change the mode. For example with this line in .tmux.conf (assuming you have TERM set to xterm):
>
> set -g terminal-overrides "xterm*:kLFT5=\eOD:kRIT5=\eOC:kUP5=\eOA:kDN5=\eOB:smkx@:rmkx@"
>
> Note that this will only work in tmux 1.2 and above.

Comment: Doesnt work. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+b` then release both and then `Ctrl+arrow key` to adjust size(holding `Ctrl` press fast multiple times arrow if needed)

Make sure that you don't have a long pause between pressing, otherwise it will resize just one step at time

Comment: That's what I am doing and it doesn't work

Comment: Pause between `Ctrl+b` and subsequent `Ctrl+arrow key` must be as short as possible, (I think it a second, no more). This bothered me too until I found that it need to be entered pretty fast

Comment: Using Putty 0.69 on Windows and tmux 2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04, Ctrl + Arrow is just detected the same as arrow without Ctrl. Setting the terminal overrides as suggested in the other answer fixes things.