# Why is tmux not recognizing ctrl+shift+arrow through MobaXterm?

Tags: ssh, tmux, mobaxterm

I've configured `tmux` so that `ctrl`+`shift`+`left/right arrow` moves windows left/right in their numerical arrangement.

I.e.:

```
# ~/.tmux.conf
...
bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1
...
```

This works fine when I'm physically at the PC where tmux is running, but does not work when I `ssh` to the PC using `MobaXterm`.

I assume that because this works when I am physically at the PC, this indicates a problem with a MobaXterm setting - **is there something I can set so that `ctrl`+`shift`+`left/right arrow` are "recognized" the same way across `MobaXterm`'s `ssh` session as they are through a directly-connected keyboard?**

I have tried the accepted answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1165287/ctrl-arrow-keys-for-tmux-not-working-in-putty) - it did not work. That question is not quite identical, though: it was about `ctrl`+`arrow`, not `ctrl`+`shift`+`arrow`, so perhaps some slight tweak is needed to that accepted answer, but the syntax of the line is obtuse to me - I can't see how it would need to be modified to support `ctrl`+`shift`+`arrow` instead of `ctrl`+`arrow` (if it is even what's needed).

```
$ tmux -V
tmux 2.9a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `cat` outside tmux in MobaXterm, then press C-S-Left, what do you see? Is it different from when you press C-Left or press Left without any modifier keys?

*IF* it is different for all three, you can configure them. If not you can only configure the ones that are unique.

You can change them in terminal-overrides, kRIT5 is C-Right, kLFT5 is C-Left, kUP5 is C-Up, kDN5 is C-Down. For C-S-Right use kRIT6, kLFT6 and so on. The numbers are:

```
       3       Alt
       4       Shift + Alt
       5       Control
       6       Shift + Control
       7       Alt + Control
       8       Shift + Alt + Control
```

S-Left is plain kLFT - no number - and same for S-Right (kRIT) and so on.

So for C-S-Left you want kLFT6, kRIT6, kUP6, kDN6.

For example for C-S-Left you might see (you won't see this because if you did it would be working, but this is an example):

```
^[[1;6D
```

As I said above, make sure this is unique, many terminals do not support all modifiers.

`^[` is Escape, so it goes into terminal-overrides as `\E`.

terminal-overrides is a set of comma-separated entries. Each entry is a colon-separated list of capabilities. The first is a pattern to match against `TERM`.

You will need to make sure MobaXterm is using a different `TERM` than your local computer or you will end up overriding the local terminal too. If both are using `xterm`, try making MobaXterm `xterm-color` or something instead, or copy `xterm` by doing `infocmp -x xterm >copy` then editing copy to change the name at the start (second line before the `|`) and installing it again with `tic -x copy`. Obviously you will need to configure MobaXterm to set this different `TERM` (or do it in your shell profile based on eg `SSH_CONNECTION` or something).

Then you can add them in terminal-overrides like this:

```
set -as terminal-overrides ',myxterm:kLFT6=\E[1;6D:kRIT6=\E[1;6C'
```

Make sure you restart tmux entirely after changing .tmux.conf, or detach and reattach after changing terminal-overrides from a running tmux.

Comment: This looked promising, but didn't work.
As advised, outside tmux in MobaXterm,  `Left` gives `^[[D`, `C-Left` gives `^[[1;5D`, and `C-S-Left` gives `^[OD`. So the three are distinct.
Based on this and your notes, I added the line `set -as terminal-overrides ',myxterm:kLFT6=\EOD:kRIT6=\EOC'` in my `~/.tmux.conf`, and restarted tmux, but the `C-S-Left/Right` keys were still not recognized.

Did I understand/implement your answer correctly, or did I mess something up? Or do you have other ideas what might be wrong/how to fix? Thank you.

Comment: Did you create a new terminfo entry called `myxterm` using `infocmp -x`/`tic -x` and set `TERM` to `myxterm` in MobaXterm? The `myxterm` bit of the `terminal-overrides` example must match `TERM` *outside* tmux, this is how tmux knows when to apply these overrides. And since you only want to do that for MobaXterm and not your other terminal, it must be unique to MobaXterm. So you can either create a new one yourself, or use an existing variant of `xterm` like `xterm-color` in MobaXterm.

Comment: My $TERM outside of tmux in MobaXterm was `xterm-256color` so I tried changing the `myxterm` to `xterm-256color` and restarting tmux, but it still didn't work. This feels really close to the right solution, just some little thing I'm missing somewhere.  

So, `c-s-left` gives `^[OD` and `c-s-right` gives `^[OC` and my entry in .`tmux.conf` is: `set -as terminal-overrides ',xterm-256color:kLFT6=\EOD:kRIT6=\EOC'`  

Do I have that right, or am I glitching somewhere?

Comment: That looks right to me. Check `tmux info|grep kLFT6` inside tmux matches `\033OD`. Also what do you see if you now run `cat` inside tmux and press `C-S-Left`?

Comment: `^[OC` is normally `Left` or `C-Left` not `C-S-Left`. If you want tmux to send it as `C-S-Left`, you may need to remove any other entries for this escape sequence - look at `tmux info|grep OC` inside tmux, if there are any others (there may be probably `kcuf1`) then add them to terminal-overrides like this: `set -as terminal-overrides ',xterm-256color:kcuf1@'`. I suspect your terminal actually only supports two kinds of arrow key, no modifiers (`Left`) and either `S-Left` or `C-Left`. Do all of `Left`, `C-Left`, `S-Left` and `C-S-Left` send unique sequences when you try them with `cat`?

Comment: **outside tmux** they're all unique: `Left` gives `^[[D`, `S-Left` gives `^[[1;2D`, `C-Left` gives `^[[1;5D` and `C-S-Left` gives `^[OD`. But **In tmux**, `Left` gives `^[[D`, `S-Left` gives `^[[1;2D`, `C-Left` gives `^[[1;5D` and `C-S-Left` gives `^[[D` -- so they are not all unique: there's a conflict between `Left` and `C-S-Left`. So perhaps that's the problem here: as you said, all those key-combinations need to be unique, but they appear to not be.

Comment: `tmux info | grep kLFT6` inside tmux gave me `150: kLFT6: (string) \033[1;6D`

Comment: That `tmux info` output shows your `terminal-overrides` isn't working.  Are you sure you restarted tmux entirely (`tmux kill-server`)? Does `tmux show -s terminal-overrides` show your `kLFT6` change? Are you sure it is `xterm-256color` outside (the top few lines of `tmux info` should show it)?

Comment: This is really weird - my PC rebooted, or something similar outside my control happened, but after coming back up, suddenly your suggestion worked! I used the `C-S-Left/Right` keybindings (`^[D` and `^[C`) from _inside_ tmux in the `terminal-overrides` section in `.tmux.comf`, and it magically started working!

Previously, I tried stopping/restarting `tmux` multiple times - but the above never worked; but after the apparent power-cycle, it did. Weird.

Thanks for all your help from before: you get answer credit!